# Why can I instantiate this abstract class?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, instance, abstract-class

I'm trying to understand abstract classes in Java so I wrote this code snippet in IntelliJ:

```
AutoCloseable ac = new BufferedInputStream(new InputStream() {
        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            return 0;
        }
});
```

The `@Override` and `read()` stub was created automatically by IntelliJ.

Since `InputStream` is an abstract class, why can I instantiate it with the `new` keyword?

---

And another thing. When I delete the method stub like this:

```
AutoCloseable ac = new BufferedInputStream(new InputStream());
```

The IDE says that `InputStream` is abstract and therefore can't be instantiated (as expected).

So, why is the former valid and the latter not?

And where does this `read()` method come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not instantiating `InputStream` in the first example. You are instantiating an anonymous class that extends `InputStream` and implements the only abstract method of `InputStream` - `read()`. That anonymous class is not abstract, so you can instantiate it.

On the other hand, `new InputStream()` attempts to instantiate an abstract class, which is not possible.